# Stone Weierstrass theorem application

Tags: real-analysis

Let $B$ be an algebra of continuous real valued function defined on a compact topological space $X$ which separates the points of $X$. Show that the closure of $B$ in $C(X)$ with respect to uniform metric is either all of $C(X)$ or else that there exist some $a \in X$ such that closure of $B$ is $ \{ f \in C(X):f(a)=0 \}$ .

Comment: I would strongly advise you familiarize yourself with MathJax.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $B$ vanishes nowhere Stone Weirstrass implies that $B$ is dense. Otherwise, let $Z$ be the set of zeroes of $B$, $a\in Z$, if $b\in Z$ distinct of $a$, there exists $f\in B$ such that $f(b)\neq f(a)$ since $B$ separates the points, this implies $f(b)\neq 0$. Contradiction. We deduce that $Z$ is $\{a\}$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Locally_compact_version

Comment: how does it contain constant function 1?